# Possible to make the Windows 8 start menu less fancy for VNC?

Tags: vnc, desktop, windows-8, start-menu

I use Windows 8 on a virtual machine through a VNC connection. The VNC server is integrated into VMWare so that even if I lose network connection on Windows 8, I can still access it.

Overall, my experience with it is pretty tolerable, except for when I go to the start menu. Bringing up just the start menu doesn't induce any amount of lag, but when I have to scroll it literally takes 5 to 10 seconds for the screen to draw for the 2 or 3 frames of scrolling. This is very annoying and is the only thing like this. Honestly, I don't really understand why it happens here either as it looks like something perfect for copy-rect to make fast. (ie, scrolling in firefox doesn't have this kind of behavior)

Anyway, has anyone else had this problem and know of anything to try to make it better?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Microsoft really intended for anyone using a traditional PC to ever scroll the start menu. They seem to be pushing a whole different workflow for finding programs. Instead of opening the start menu and scrolling to find your program, they want you to hit the Windows key and immediately start typing the name of what you are looking for. Your hand never leaves the keyboard, and the visual cues involved in the process keep a more static background that is friendly on remote access systems like VNC.

So, in summary, to make the start menu work better with VNC:

1. Hit the Windows key
2. Type the first few letters of the item you're looking for.

Comment: Heh, except for their search algorithm has become much less useful compared to Windows 7. In 7 I can bring up the start menu and type `dot` and it will bring up a `dotfuscator` icon(as I want)... in 8, I have to type it out completely to get it to bring it up. Sigh. Who thought Windows 8 was a good idea again? lol

Comment: @Earlz: Partial name matches work for me in Win8.

Comment: Get power8 http://code.google.com/p/power8/ or start8 http://www.stardock.com/products/start8/

Comment: @Karan for me it only works up til a space. For instance, `vir` won't bring up visual studio, but `visual` will.